# Choose a random item from a table

Tags: random, lua

My goal is to pick out a random item from a table in Lua.

This is what I've got so far, but it currently does not work:

```
local myTable = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }
print( myTable[ math.random( 0, #myTable - 1 ) ] )
```

How can I fix the above code so that it works as intended? (Or which other method could I use?)

Comment: Thought I'd add to this. Yes, by default the first index in a lua array is 1. However, you could have it start at 0 like so: array = {[0] = 'a', 'b', 'c'} print(array[0]) >> a 'b' will follow suit at index 1 and 'c' at index 2...

Answer (score 82):

Lua indexes tables from 1, unlike C, Java etc. which indexes arrays from 0. That means, that in your table, the valid indexes are: 1, 2, 3, 4. What you are looking for is the following:

```
print( myTable[ math.random( #myTable ) ] )
```

When called with one argument, `math.random(n)` returns a random integer from 1 to `n` including.

Answer (score 24):

I think the question also needs a more general answer. There is no limitation on lua tables to be built with a sequence of integers starting from 1. Keys can be really anything - they could even be other lua tables! In such cases, functions like #myTable might give an answer you don't expect (when used without any custom metatable functionality). The only reliable way to get all keys in a table is to iterate over it:

```
-- iterate over whole table to get all keys
local keyset = {}
for k in pairs(myTable) do
    table.insert(keyset, k)
end
-- now you can reliably return a random key
random_elem = myTable[keyset[math.random(#keyset)]]
```

I will also add that the original solution by [Michal Kottman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988502) would work perfectly if all your keys are a sequence of numbers starting from 1. This happens whenever you create a table as `myTable = {'a','b','c'}`. So for situations where tables are built this way, getting random elements from the table would be faster his way.

Answer (score 3):

Test:

```
t = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
print(t[0])
```

gives `nil`. In fact 0 is out of bounds (try `t[20]`)... so random must be from 1 to `#myTable` (inclusive) because the first element of a [table](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) is labeled (indexed) as 1 if you write just `exp`, see [Table constructor](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) ("*Finally, fields of the form exp are equivalent to [i] = exp, where i are consecutive integers starting with 1.*").

If you pass to [math.random](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.7) just an argument `n`, you obtain a random number from 1 to `n` inclusive. This fixes your example:

```
print(myTable[math.random(#myTable)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table = {'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Watermelon' , 'lychee'} --my table have 5 item.

rand= math.random(1~5) --create a random number numbers 1 to 5 if more than 5 then the value is nil.

print(rand)
print(table[rand]) --unite the random number and item it will display 5 random items in the table.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function randomObjectFromTable(t)
   return t[math.random(1, #t)]
end
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the following function inspired by @ahmadh

```
function random_elem(tb)
    local keys = {}
    for k in pairs(tb) do table.insert(keys, k) end
    return tb[keys[math.random(#keys)]]
end
```