# Love2d: random element from table

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table, love2d

I'm trying to get a item randomly from a table. I have searched online but all the code I have found didn't work. My table looks like this:

```
section = {a, b}
love.graphics.newImage("/Images/a.png")
love.graphics.newImage("/Images/b.png")     
love.graphics.draw(section[imath.random(#section)], x, y)
```

I need a random item from this table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua choose random item from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988246/lua-choose-random-item-from-table)

Comment: Both answers from [Lua choose random item from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988246/lua-choose-random-item-from-table) don't works with letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
item = section[math.random(#section)]
```

In your example:

```
section = {
   love.graphics.newImage("/Images/a.png"),
   love.graphics.newImage("/Images/b.png"),
}    
love.graphics.draw(section[math.random(#section)], x, y)
```

Comment: @math.random, if you want letters, use `section = {"a", "b", "c", "f", "z"}`.

Comment: i need this to load a random .png. This is the code: `love.graphics.newImage("/Images/a.png") .... love.graphics.newImage("/Images/b.png") love.graphics.draw(section[imath.random(#section)], x, y)`